# Is there any possible solution to detect when Android OS kill background Service?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-service, background-service

I'm working on android based application and facing a problem on VIVO Y15s [Funtouch OS 12 Global] that this device kill background service/task automatically after 5 to 6 minutes. and there is no exception or any error appear in the android studio logs.
So please please guide me if u have any solution regarding this problem.

I tried many possible solution and also override the onDestroy() and onTaskRemoved() methods but not succeed. In these method i put service restart mechanism.

```
val restartServiceIntent = Intent(applicationContext, AppService::class.java).also {
    it.setPackage(packageName)
    it.action = Actions.START.name
}
val restartServicePendingIntent: PendingIntent =
    PendingIntent.getService(this, 1, restartServiceIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE)
val alarmService: AlarmManager =
    applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
alarmService.set(
    AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000,
    restartServicePendingIntent
)
```

Comment: You should prompt the user to disable battery optimisation for your app, if you want to retain the service in background. Further you can detect service termination using onDestroy method. Further it depends on what you want to achieve when a service is killed in background

Comment: Thanks for response , actually problem that when system kill the background service then  onDestroy() didn't called and also there is no exception or any type of error appear in the log in android studio , this issue is happened in only in vivo device name above mention.

Comment: Can you also attach service code? And after how long does service get terminated?

Comment: bro my service class contains thousands of lines of code so unable to add here ....

Comment: So when does your service gets terminated after starting? Like in next 2-5 mins or after some considerable time? Also Have you requested for disabling battery optimisation? Please try to answer all question, you just answer only one part of question